# Is it possible to extract job from big query to GCS across project ids?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Hey guys trying to export a bigquery table to cloud storage a la [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/export_data_to_cloud_storage.py) .  Not working for me at the moment, am worried that the reason is that the cloud storage project is different to the bigquery table, is this actually doable?  I can't see how using that template above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirming:
You CAN have your table in ProjectA to be exported/extracted to GCS bucket in ProjectB. You just need make sure you have proper permissions on both sides. At least:

`READ` for respective dataset in Project A and
and
`WRITE` for respective bucket in Project B

**`Please note`**: Data in respective dataset of Project A and bucket in Project B - MUST be in the same location - US or EU , etc.
Simply to say: sourse and destination must be in the same location